# Converting python to shell script

Tags: scripts, python, convert

I was wandering if there is a way to translate python to shell script, because I have a .py script and I wanted to translate it to a shell script.

Comment: Couple of things to note: 1) I am not aware of an automated way to translate Python to Bash; 2) this question is better suited for Stack Overflow, but Stack Overflow is not a code writing/translation service, so don't expect to dump your Python script there and hope someone will translate everything to Bash for you.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to solve your problem:

1. Convert the python script to bash step-by-step (I doubt there is an automated process to do that).
2. Use [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to create a binary executable for Linux.

Comment: PyInstaller is indeed a good solution.